CMC Current Rating
I need to pick a common mode choke which goes in series with an acdc converter.

Maximum output power of the acdc is 30W(5V, 6A), if we assume no worse thn 70% efficiency, this means no more than ~43W on the AC side giving a max. cont input current of 0.19A.
With that in mind, any of the listed shall be within current rating spec.
What I am worried about is transient effects ie. ACDC having bulk capacitance at the input causing this current to maybe go above the current rating for short periods of time? Is this something that I shall consider when picking a value?

Yes, for heating you need to consider RMS input current, which can be considerably higher than average current because the input current curve is spiky. You can measure it with a true RMS meter.
It will be maximum at maximum output current and minimum input voltage.

You’ll be hard pressed to overheat a CMC from the inrush current in most applications. If you have so high and long inrush current to begin to overheat your CMC, the fuse have already blown or some UL or CE requirement been violated.
For normal operation, see Sphero’s answer.
